I get an error when I want to access a data class from an entity
I have the following entity and would like to create an attribute from another data class (Deposit.kt).

Unfortunately I get the following error when compiling. Error creating
bean with name 'refreshEventListener': Singleton bean creation not
allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not
request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
Could not determine recommended JdbcType for de.stromee.orderup.offer.domain.Deposit

NewOffer.kt:
  @Entity
  data class NewOffer(

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  var uniqueId: UUID? = UUID.randomUUID(),
  ...

  var deposit: Deposit

  )

Deposit.kt:
 data class Deposit (
  var brutto: Number?,
  var netto: Number?,
  var divisor: Number?,
)


have you tried using nullable reference as var deposit: Deposit?   ?
